# sound is playing in simulator but not on physical device

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, simulator

My xcode sound is not playing on a ipad but is playing on the xcode simulator. I downloaded my app from the appstore and the sound was not there as well. I have tried multiple file formats including mp3, aac,wav etc and none of them are playing. I dont know what is going on because I have used this code before and it worked fine.

```
import UIKit;import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player : AVAudioPlayer?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bell.mp3", ofType:nil)!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            print("ran")
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player?.play()
        } catch {
            // couldn't load file :(
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Is your iPad's volume muted?

Comment: or it might be connected to other output ;)

Comment: There's a few things that may help nail this down that fall between "Simulator", "Downloaded", and "iPad". The obvious first one - how about an iPhone? Second, what's the actual result of running this code? Third, how about using this "iPad" in Xcode, where you can debug things? And sure, I guess I'm asking for something duplicatable, and something to eliminate the "downloaded" portion of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double check the code you've posted is not falling into the catch block. You should see an error in the console if an error is produced.

```
do {
    print("ran")
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    player?.play()
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

You should also check the device is not on silent. To prevent this you can use the below that will always the play the audio as the audio sessions category will be set to `.playback`

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: You were totally right is was a silent issue my new ipad does not have the switch for silent mode is somehow it was just on it.

Comment: The second suggestion here worked for me with a MAUI iOS app that would not play audio under any circumstances using the standard audio plugin (Plugin.Maui.Audio). Thanks so much- this is such a simple fix I need to recommend they add this into the plugin too.